# how to apply join on self table

Tags: sql, left-join, hierarchical-data, self-join

I have Emp table having 3 columns [EmpId], [EmpName], [MgrId]
MgrId is foreign key of same Emp table and EmpId is primary key

```
EmpId   EmpName MgrId
1       A       NULL
2       B       1
3       C       2
4       D       3
5       E       4
```

I need following output

```
EmpName MgrName
A        
B       A
C       B
D       C
E       D
```

I am using following query but getting wrong output

```
SELECT E1.EmpName, E1.Empname as mgrName
FROM Emp E1, Emp E2 
WHERE E1.EmpId = E2.EmpId
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a self-join indeed, but:

- the join condition needs to be fixed: you want to match the manager against the employee
- it has to be a `LEFT JOIN`, so employees without a manager are not fitered out
- you want to the manager name in the `select` clause

So:

```
SELECT E1.EmpName, E2.Empname as mgrName
FROM Emp E1
LEFT JOIN Emp E2 ON E2.EmpID = E1.MgrID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E1.EMPNAME, E2.EMPNAME AS MGRNAME
FROM EMP E1 
LEFT JOIN EMP E2 
ON E1.MGR = E2.EMPID
```